# isEqualToString always return YES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have this line of code

```
if ([[dateTextField text] isEqualToString:@"Test"]);
{
}
```

For some reason it is always returning YES even when [textfield text] doesn't equal Test.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

remove `;` at end of if statement

Answer (score 2):

when you put ; at the end of the line then the xcode will take that as the statement.It is not taking it as condition